# "System is ready to into shipping mode" after changing settings in BIOS?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

I own an Acer Aspire 3 A315-42 R7AP laptop and today my brother entered the bios to change a Function keys setting. After pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and restart he got the following message:

[image: Screen shot showing the message below]

> System is ready to into shipping mode
>
> Please remove AC power
>
> And DON'T press power button to shutdown system!

Eventually the laptop discharged, turned off and now it won't turn on any more. When I press the power button a blue LED lights up but nothing happens, like no noise, no video on screen and so on.

I googled around and I only found a post on the Acer support website with a problem similar to mine but it offers no solution. Warranty definitely expired and I can open my laptop and remove & plug the battery back in if needed, but I'm not sure if it would be of any use.

Comment: Kudos for taking a "screen shot" of the message before it was too late.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You put the laptop into shipping mode which disconnects the battery to avoid discharging during transport. To turn it back on, you need to connect the power adapter and then press and hold the power button for five seconds.

Comment: "ready to into" WTF?

Comment: Perhaps, a word is accidentally omitted: "ready to [go] into"

Comment: @Barmar Since the text is likely intended only to be seen by Acer employees, QA may not have been as important as anything customer-facing.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, implicit in the question is wondering why it went into shipping mode. Any clue based on what the OP described? Is it a BIOS option that can be accidentally pressed? A wrong key pressed? Something that alwayas happens if you change the function keys?

Comment: It's triggered by a key combination (ctrl+F2 IIRC) in the BIOS screen which the OP's brother may have hit by mistake.

Comment: @trlkly More specifically, based on the information in [this Acer service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1772615/Acer-An515-51.html?page=103#manual) (section 2.66, pages 103-104), shift+f2 will open the Manufacturer BIOS setup screen, rather than the standard BIOS which is accessed by only pressing F2 during boot (page 40).

Comment: @Barmar: They accidentally a word...

Comment: @user96551 Or maybe "into" should be "enter".

Comment: It's [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish), @Barmar. You recognize this stuff after you deal with enough electronics developed by non-native speakers.

Comment: @CodyGray Nah, my money is on copy-pasta. I see mistakes like this in documents written by people who have a perfectly fine grasp of English but they're editing and moving text around and they accidentally miss/delete a word without realizing. Esp. software, it was probably copy-pasta'd from an e-mail or ticket tracking system, someone was changing half of the sentence but accidentally deleted an extra word.

Comment: I looks to me as if was intended to discharge the battery down to what is required for optimal storage life and safe shipping charge for lithium ion. Maybe that BIOS option was left over from a different model and not intended to be used on this model.

Comment: Knowing how to trigger the mode is useful if one plans on storing the laptop for a long time, given that the former method of simply removing the battery has gotten way more difficult.